# autohotkey, how can i make buttons on the desktop to run directly .ahk code

Tags: autohotkey

i want to make on my desktop a set of buttons, to run the autohotkey command code's direct from the buttons out if i push these with the mouse. do somebody now a software that can do that. example : send {printSreen}

Comment: If you do it for yourself then I guess you can simply make several AHK scripts and put them on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want standalone programs you can compile your individual scripts.  You'll end up with relatively large executables which you can link to your icons.

Comment: i now you can compile it into a .exe but i want to make a set of buttons that run the .ahk directly in 1 click. not from a windows shortcut link. it focus the windows. for example : paste a clipboard text to any applications . (send ^v)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Gui](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm), remove its [margin](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Margin), set it to [always on top](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Options), add various [buttons](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Button) which fire your desired subroutines and put a shortcut to it in your windows startup folder. Other than that, there is no "put buttons on the desktop" in AutoHotkey, I'm afraid.

Don't forget that you or the user may also press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or klick the Desktop symbol to get to the desktop. This might hide your ahk gui then, you'll have to think of that.

But frankly, I don't understand the sense of that. Why do the buttons have to be on your desktop? This means that you'll have to minimize everything in order to press any of the buttons. Why not create a gui and (de-)activate with a custom hotkey of your choice?

Comment: i now that you can not create buttons on the desktop in autohotkey, but that is not what i did mean. you need a other software. with [autohotkey you can send commands with your keyboard.] [keystarter 1.0 it can send autohotkey commands with your mouse.] and you do not need to minimize everthing it is [without focus the windows] if you push the buttons.